# A variable not changing

Tags: python, variables, discord, bots

I'm making a spammer discord bot that spams @everyone if someone writes 'anyone game' and stops if someone writes 'enough' in Python but I'm really new so why is the game variable not changing? It remains 0 after the correct message was sent (it sees the message)
Here's the code

```
async def on_message(message):
    username = str(message.author).split('#')[0]
    user_message = str(message.content)
    channel = str(message.channel.name)
    game = '0'
    if message.author == client.user:
        return
    if message.channel.name == 'games' and user_message.lower() == 'anyone game?':
        game = '1'
    print(f'{username}: {user_message} ({channel}) {game}') /this line is for me and this is why I know that the 'game' remains 0 and this comment is not in the code itself/


    if game == '1':
        await message.channel.send(f'anyone game? @everyone (by {username})')

    if message.channel.name == 'games' and user_message.lower() == 'enough':
            game = '0'
            await message.channel.send(f'ENOUGH')
```

(and also please explain it like if you were talking to a kid because I'm really new to programming)

Answer (score 0):

Note that you set `game = '0'` everytime the function is called. This means that the only time `game == '1'` is when the message is initially written. So if the program will only send the message once after the first "anyone game" is written.

Have you also double checked that the variables `message.channel.name` and `user_message.lower()` are correct? To see their values before the if-case you could just print them

```
print(message.channel.name)
print(user_message.lower())
```

Also, consider letting the variable `game` be set to `False` and `True` instead of the strings `'0'` and `'1'`. This usage makes more sense in your code.